# Where does Server stores source IP address extracted from incoming Packets during UDP transmission?

Tags: networking, server, udp, ip, client-server

A packet reached the server of UDP type at Transport layer. When the source IP address is extracted from the received packet by the server (at Transport Layer), where does the server stores this address, as it will be required in future, since the connection between server and client is connection-less? Or what mechanism does server use to identify source (during a connection-less environment) in order to reply?

Comment: Well, _frames_ contain layer-2 addresses, e.g. MAC addresses, not layer-3 addresses, e.g. IP addresses, which are contained in layer-3 _packets_, so the question doesn't actually makes any sense as you have it in your question. Is it possible that you misunderstood?

Comment: @RonMaupin By Frames I didn't mean only the header addresses, but also the data. Frame data contains IP addresses of Source and Destination which are extracted at Network Layer by the server. So the question is what does server do with these IP addresses (as they need to be used later on) when Transport Layer is using UDP protocol.

Comment: The frames are stripped off before the packets get sent to the network layer, so the IP addresses are exposed in the packets at the network layer. The packets are the payload of the frames, and layer-2 only passes the payload to layer-3, not caring about the payload. Layer-3 doesn't know or care about the frames because it can be carried in any number of different layer-2 protocols. Also, layer-2 frames can carry any number of layer-3 protocols, none of which but IPv4 (32-bit addresses) or IPv6 (128-bit addresses) have IP addresses, and those two IPs are not compatible.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you think the address is required in the future? It may not be.

Also, there is no such thing as client/server for the first four network layers of the OSI model. The client/server model is an application concept, not a network concept. Layer-2 (e.g. ethernet), layer-3 (e.g. IP), and layer-4 (e.g. TCP) are peer-to-peer protocols, not client/server protocols.

If an application on one host needs a reply from a host to which it sends data using UDP, it can include its host address as part of the UDP data in the application-layer protocol, and the receiving application can store the source IP and UDP addresses wherever it wants.

As you wrote, UDP is connectionless (and unreliable), and an application using UDP must assume that the UDP datagram will not arrive. The application either adds reliability as part of the application-layer protocol used, or it just doesn't care that some data *will* be lost. For instance:

Real-time applications use UDP, and some, like video applications are unidirectional. Others like VoIP use a signalling protocol to set up bidirectional traffic. Almost all real-time protocols don't want missing data to be resent because that would cause more problems. Having missing video or voice data resent, arriving out of order, would be chaos.

Comment: Suppose a client requests for some service, via connection-less, like a live video stream. When the server gets the request, it can easily extract the source address, which is in Transport Layer Header. Since the server is receiving lots of requests in any instance. It might need to store some addresses as it can't process all requests in a single go. Where and how this address is stored by the Server's OS?

Comment: I think I explained that. The application will use a protocol to set up the connection, and as part of that, the requesting host will give the receiving host its address, or you could use something like SIP (not only a VoIP protocol as many people think, but a signalling protocol to set up connections, often used for video, too).

Comment: The address is required for the kernel to deliver the data into `recvfrom()`. It can't just throw away the UDP header and keep only the data in the socket receive buffer. So it doesn't. It keeps the UDP header as well. There is no need for an application to include its own address in a UDP application protocol.

Comment: @EJP, I never said anything about throwing away the UDP (transport layer) header (which, by the way, does not contain either the source or destination IP address). What I wrote, "_..it [application] can include its host address as part of the UDP data in the application-layer protocol..._" That is precisely what happens when application use SIP (Session Initiation Protocol) or something else to set up a UDP conversation.